# Converting decimal numbers to hex

Tags: hex, decimal

I have an embedded device which stores decimal numbers in hexadecimal form but I'm having trouble with the conversion.

Here are some examples of how it stores decimal values.

```
1 = 80 3f
1.1 = cd cc 8c 3f
1.2 = 9a 99 99 3f
1.3 = 66 66 a6 3f
1.4 = 33 33 b3 3f
1.5 = c0 3f
1.6 = cd cc cc 3f
1.7 = 9a 99 d9 3f
1.8 = 66 66 e6 3f
1.9 = 33 33 f3 3f
2 = 40
7.3 = 9a 99 e9 40
```

Does anyone see what the process may be to convert these numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are big endian floats

In python they can be unpacked with the format string !f

example

```
>>> a="\x40\x00\x00\x00"
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack("!f",a)
>>> (2.0,)
```

Comment: Ok that pointed me in the right direction. With php I can use do this: `echo implode("",unpack("f*", "\xcd\xcc\xcc\x3f"));` output = 1.6000000238419